# jQuery problems with adding newlines forward

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

### Environment

Edge: 122.0.2365.66
JQuery: 1.2

### Problem Description

```js
$("#xodv3fdv25gz span:nth-child(2)").before("<br>")
$("#xodv3fdv25gz span:nth-child(3)").before("<br>")
```

[image: failure effect]

The effect is in front of the second `span`。

```js
$("#xodv3fdv25gz span:nth-child(3)").before("<br>")
$("#xodv3fdv25gz span:nth-child(2)").before("<br>")
```

After swapping locations, it can operate normally.

[image: success effect]

I wish I knew why.

I'd appreciate it if you'd help me.

Comment: `nth-child()` is not doing what you think it does.  It's not "select all spans then the 2nd of those spans" - that would `:eq(..)` (which is *deprecated* so would be `.eq(..)`).  `:nth-child(3)` is select all spans then filtering to the element that is *also* the 3rd child - as you insert something before that span is now the 4th child, so `:nth-child(3)` no longer matches it.  It works the other way as you insert your first `br` *after* the 2nd child, so it's position is not changed.   I'm sure there's an existing question on this, so a comment only.

Comment: Well, when you insert a br, all the nth children become `n+1`th

Comment: you could use `:nth-of-type` - except you, for some reason, use the version of jquery before jquery understood `nth-of-type` ... i.e. version 1.3 good, version 1.2 bad, and about 1000 years old - OK, 16.5 years, but in web programming terms, that's about 1000 years

Comment: When this happens, you should debug your code by displaying what your jQuery selection returns, obviously previous comments are right, after you insert your `<br>`, the third child is the same span you selected the first time, because the `<br>` is inserted before and it changes the number of children. With a simple `console.log` you could have found it yourself. One solution could be to select all spans first in variables, and add the `<br>` after all is selected

Comment: jquery 1.3, released *January 14, 2009* - probably about time for an upgrade?

Comment: would this work? `$("#xodv3fdv25gz span.inline").after("<br>")`

Answer (score 0):

You should be storing the result of you css query selectors in local variables.
This becomes even more important if you execute commands that alter the DOM and modify the expected output of your subsequent query selectors.

It is also generally a good practice to check the length of a jQuery object to determine if any elements were matched by your selector.

```
const _2ndSpan = $("#xodv3fdv25gz span:nth-child(2)")
const _3rdSpan = $("#xodv3fdv25gz span:nth-child(3)")

if(_2ndSpan.length === 1) _2ndSpan.before("<br>")
if(_3rdSpan.length === 1) _3rdSpan.before("<br>")
```